# Python multithreading in endlessloop

Tags: python, multithreading

Hallo I'm quit new to the topic of multithreading and processing in python.

In my current problem I have 4 different task that should run in an endless loop.

The runtimes of those tasks are about

- T1(green): 0.4s
- T2(blue): ~0.6-0.8s
- T3(black): ~0.6-0.8s
- T4(red): 0.02s
  [image]

The latest resuts from T1 and T4 are input paramertes for T2 and T3.

T2/T3 should always start together when the results from T1 and T4 are there and the results from T2 and T3 should be merged to the endresult

Furthermote to reduce the runtime of T2 and T3 they always should run in parallel / on there own process.

pseudocode:

```py
while true:
      result4 = worker4().run().result()
      if task1.done()
              result1 = task1.result()
              task1 = worker1().run()

      if (result1 and result4) and (task2.stopped() and task3.stopped()):
              task2 = worker2(result1).run()
              task3 = worker3(result2).run()

      if task2.done() and task3.done():
         endresult = task2.result() + task3.result()
```

I made multiple attempts to solve the problem with [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Process.join) and [ThreadPoolExecutor](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html)
but I haven't found any good solution to run them in an endless loop.

Solution1 with ThreadPoolExecutor:

```py
def worker1():
    time.sleep(50)
    return "result1"

def worker2(result):
    time.sleep(80)
    return "endresult" + result

def worker4():
    return "result4"

result1, result2, thread1, thread2, thread3= None, None, None, None, None

with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=4) as executor:
    while True:
        result4 = worker4()
        
        if thread1 is None:
                 thread1 = executor.submit(worker1)
        if thread1.done():
                 result1 = thread1.result()

        if (thread2 is None and thread3 is None) and (result1 not None and result2 not None):
               thread2 = executor.submit(worker3, result1)
               thread3 = executor.submit(worker3, result2)
               result1, result2 = None, None

        if (thread2 is not None and thread3 is not None)
                if thread2.done() and thread3.done():
                         frameDict = {}
                         result = [thread2.result(), thread3.result()]
                         thread2, thread3 = None, None

        time.sleep(10)
```

This Solution kind of worked for me but thread 2 and 3 where slow/not parallel

So I tried and implementation with multiprocessing but there is the problem that I dont know when a process is done.

```py
def worker1():
    time.sleep(50)
    return "result1"

def worker2(q, result):
    time.sleep(80)
    q.put( "endresult" + result)

def worker4(q):
    q.put("result4")

result1, result4, thread1, thread2, thread3= None, None, None, None, None

X = 1 # When 0 Task 2 and 3 will run very slow

while True:
     result4 = worker4()
        
    if thread1 is None:
            thread1 =  multiprocessing.Process(target=worker1 , args=(q, ))
    thread1.join(X)

    if (thread2 is None and thread3 is None) and (thread1.is_alive() == False and result4 not None):
            thread2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=worker2, args=(q, q.get()))
            thread2.start()
            thread3 = multiprocessing.Process(target=worker2, args=(q, result4))
            thread3.start()
            result1, result4 = None, None

    thread2.join(X)
    thread3.join(X)

    if thread2 is not None and thread3 is not None:
        if thread2.is_alive() == False and thread3.is_alive() == False:
            endresult = [q.get(), q.get()]
            
    time.sleep(10)
```

Notes:

- When I use  `process.join(1)`  the mainthread with the contious worker will be paused for a short time which should not happen.
- `thread1.is_alive()` should change to False after the join but it never does. As an alternativate I used `q.qsize()`  to check if the results are there or not.

I would be happy when someone could provide me with a guide or an basic example on how to work with those processes in an endless loop.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [MPipe](https://vmlaker.github.io/mpipe/) library for creating a pipeline architecture. Example :

```
from mpipe import OrderedStage, Pipeline

def increment(value):
    return value + 1

def double(value):
    return value * 2

stage1 = OrderedStage(increment, 3)
stage2 = OrderedStage(double, 3)
pipe = Pipeline(stage1.link(stage2))

for number in range(10):
    pipe.put(number)

pipe.put(None)

for result in pipe.results():
    print(result)
```